# Count Option in Twitter4J getFriendsList

Tags: twitter4j

According to twitter documentation at https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1.1/get/friends/list
URL, I can change the value of "count"(The number of users to return per page) from default 20 to 200. But how can I specify the count option while calling getFriendsList api using Twitter4J java library.

Answer (score 1):

According to the [documentation](http://twitter4j.org/oldjavadocs/3.0.3/index.html) if you're using `getFriendsList` you can only request up to 20 at a time. Might be a limitation of this java API

```
PagableResponseList<User> getFriendsList(long userId,
                                   long cursor)
                                     throws TwitterException
cursor - Causes the results to be broken into pages of no more than 20 records at a time.
```

Comment: Which other java/any_other_lang library supports the count Option?

Comment: Based on Kai's answer you probably could create your own method that also takes count as a parameter and pass that along.

Answer (score 1):

The [count parameter](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1.1/get/friends/list) is not used in Twitter4J at the moment (as of 3.0.3).
This is what the code in question [looks like](https://github.com/yusuke/twitter4j/blob/master/twitter4j-core/src/main/java/twitter4j/TwitterImpl.java#L550-566):

```
public PagableResponseList<User> getFriendsList(long userId, long cursor) throws TwitterException {
    return factory.createPagableUserList(get(conf.getRestBaseURL() 
       + "friends/list.json?user_id=" + userId
       + "&cursor=" + cursor));
}
```

and

```
public PagableResponseList<User> getFriendsList(String screenName, long cursor) throws TwitterException {
    return factory.createPagableUserList(get(conf.getRestBaseURL() 
       + "friends/list.json?screen_name=" + screenName
       + "&cursor=" + cursor));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In order to retrieve more users with Twitter4J you'll have to use [cursors](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/misc/cursoring) and make multiple api calls, e.g.:

```
long cursor = -1;
PagableResponseList<User> friends;
do {
     friends = twitter.getFriendsList(userId, cursor);
     // collect users be adding to list etc...
} while ((cursor = followers.getNextCursor()) != 0);
```

N.B. A cursor value of zero signifies no further results.

Answer (score 0):

Your code should look this way :

```
     long cursor=-1;
     int count=0;

     while(cursor!=0)
     {
           PagableResponseList<User> friendlist= twitter.getFriendsList(user.getScreenName(),cursor);
             int sizeoffreindlist= friendlist.size();
           for(int i=0;i<sizeoffreindlist;i++)
         {

             //System.out.println(friendlist.get(i));
                    //Your Logic goes here

         }
         cursor=friendlist.getNextCursor();
         System.out.println("====> New cursor value"+cursor);
     }
```

Twitter responses cursor value 0 when no other pagable response i.e there are is no more friend list

Comment: This is not the solution to the question.

Answer (score 0):

The fix for this was checked into the code on 4/29/2014 (see [this commit](https://github.com/yusuke/twitter4j/commit/ee322a7e54ad73591bfba3e828fc250a603d885e)) and is available in the 4.0.2 Snapshot build today. So this will be part of v 4.0.2 and above.